# Ember: Inserting 100 components, and setting an attribute for each

Tags: ember.js

I'm playing with creating a drag and drop feature. I'm trying to create a grid, to drag elements onto, and then carry out some action based on the drop element.

I've created components for dragging and dropping. To create the grid, I want to insert a couple of hundred or so of the droppable components, and give each one a unique number I can use inside the components template.

How should I insert 100 elements and give the unique attribute to each?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you need a number. The components can send actions up using their `this`, as in `this.sendAction('dropped', this)`.

Comment: I'm sure there's better ways, but I want to save the positions of the dragged elements, and be able to reload them and their position on the grid on subsequent instances, and across different screen sizes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could operate your logic by **model instances** (I mean model concept here, it could be some `array` of objects or `records array`).

It's clear that you have `model` (as some array), since you mentioned "grid of 100 elements".

You could create list components through model instances, for example:

```
{{!-- list of components --}}
{{#each model as |item|}}
  {{cell-component item=item uniqAttr=item.yourUniqAttribute actionDrop="actionDrop"}}
{{/each}}
```

where you could pass unique attribute to `cell-component` through `item` and send action `actionDrop`.

Comment: Yeah pretty much this. Except that its nothing to do with the model per se, its just to make a 10x10 or 20x20 grid. So I made an array in the controller. Cheers